# Wireshark GUI incredibly wide

Tags: qt, homebrew, wireshark

Wireshark 2.0.5 on OSX 10.10.5 with QT4.8 generates an incredibly wide GUI window.

I can't find anything at all on how to resolve this. It starts up and then immediately grows to be 3 times the width of my screen and I cannot make the window smaller horizontally.

Wireshark was installed via homebrew with `brew install wireshark --with-qt` and homebrew claims it is fully up to date.

[Really wide wireshark GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVoIu.png)

Compiled (64-bit) with Qt 4.8.7, with libpcap, without POSIX capabilities, with
libz 1.2.5, with GLib 2.48.1, without SMI, with c-ares 1.11.0, without Lua, with
GnuTLS 3.4.14, with Gcrypt 1.7.2, with MIT Kerberos, with GeoIP, with
QtMultimedia, without AirPcap.

Running on Mac OS X 10.10.5, build 14F1808 (Darwin 14.5.0), with locale C, with
libpcap version 1.5.3 - Apple version 47, with libz 1.2.5, with GnuTLS 3.4.14,
with Gcrypt 1.7.2.
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770HQ CPU @ 2.20GHz (with SSE4.2)

Built using clang 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81).

Comment: Can you try installing the official package from wireshark.org, or pass "--with-qt5" to the brew install command? We don't build or test on OS X using Qt 4 and I have no idea how well it will behave. I *really* wish the homebrew folks would make Qt5 the default "--with-qt" option.

Comment: --with-qt5 did it. Thanks!